# Not able to insert data into table using SqlDataAdapter and stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, null, insert, sqldataadapter

I have code to pick data from a Windows form application and load into my SQL Server table. I wrote the query shown here, but the insert is not working. On debugging I am getting a null exception error. I am not able to figure out what is causing the null exception. Please help

```
public bool insert(contactClass c)
{
    bool isSuccess = false;
    dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        // while debugging control goes to catch due to null exception
        SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_contact", db.con);
                
        adp1.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                
        adp1.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", 2);
        adp1.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", c.FirstName);
        adp1.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", c.LastName);
        adp1.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactno", c.ContactNo);
        adp1.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", c.Address);
        adp1.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", c.Gender);

        adp1.Update(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            isSuccess = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isSuccess = false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        string msg = e.Message;
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Obligatory: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) And, [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Could you edit your question, please, to include the full and complete error message - as text - along with highlighting which line of code the error gets thrown from?